# Transparent Alpha textures and Freestyle rendering

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency, freestyle

[image](Using version 2.83)

When I use Transparent alpha and render image with Freestyle it keeps rendering transparent Edges and are visible, how do I make them invisible?

Comment: You can disable render object outline , but it disables for whole render. Why do you need freestyle?

Comment: Yes that's true, Freestyle is one of the technique I render my images with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In blender 2.9 how do I get freestyle to ignore transparent materials on a vroid character](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203277/in-blender-2-9-how-do-i-get-freestyle-to-ignore-transparent-materials-on-a-vroid)

Answer (score 1):

Move all objects that shouldn't have freestyle outlines to a new collection (you can select them, press <kbd>M</kbd> and create a new collection or choose an existing one). Then, in *View Layer* tab, inside *Freestyle* section, select the freestyle condition to also be based on a collection - then precise the new collection and choose *exclusive* to not draw over objects from that collection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Markus, thank you very much, it works, amazing thanks again.